# multivariate analysis in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, multivariate-testing

I am looking to identify packages that allow for multivariate analysis.. e.g., multiple dependent variables (e.g., Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4) fit to the same set of predictors, in R.

I know it can be done through multivariate multiple regression with the lm function, but is there a way through neural nets, svm, any sort of ensemble methods; or just other methods to rpedict multiple dependent variables that are correlated.

Answer (score -1):

Just take a look to the cran repository: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/neuralnet.pdf

Comment: By the way if you want to use models the glm, gam, randomforrest etc. are nicely implemented. The random forrest models are relatively weak in it's prediction power but you'll get easy access to the variable importance.

Comment: Hi Julian - I have searched there and those packages are not being revealing. The random forest item suggests it cannot be done. Do you have any additional hints or resources? Thank you.